# curve_fit() producing flat line

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I'm trying to fit a Cauchy distribution to 2D data stored in a .csv file. I can't for the life of me work out why I just get a flat line for the distribution.

Any help getting the distribution to fit the data is much appreciated!

Code is as follows:

```
from scipy.stats import cauchy
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


def cauchy_pdf(x, loc, scale):
    return cauchy.pdf(x, loc, scale)


data = pd.read_csv('../camera_array_1.csv')
x = data['Distance_pixels'].values
y = data['Gray_Value'].values

popt, pcov = curve_fit(cauchy_pdf, x, y)

loc, scale = popt

plt.scatter(x, y, label='Data')
plt.plot(x, cauchy_pdf(x, *popt), 'r-')
plt.show()
```

[image: Plot showing flat line]

[.csv file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hgwFdHl8R4WWskMdyV_e-99OO2V7xzHD/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Try setting the initial fitting parameters `x` and `y` to a reasonable estimate (estimated just by eye) of the actual values.

Comment: Would you please upload CSV via Google Drive link so that members can easily solve it?

Comment: @Nameless post edited with link to csv.

Comment: @9769953 how do I do that?
Also, I want to auto fit the curve as I have to do hundreds of these...

Comment: You can estimate `loc` from the largest value(s) of y, then use argmax to get the corresponding x position. Or just `mean(x)`, and `std(x)` should be enough to give decent starting points for `loc` and `scale` (provided your x values are reasonably well distributed).

Comment: The Cauchy PDF cannot fit your data without the use of an additional parameter. It is clear from your plot that the area under the curve implied by your data is far greater than 1. Try including an amplitude parameter, e.g. `def scaled_cauchy_pdf(x, a, loc, scale): return a*cauchy.pdf(x, loc, scale)`. Also follow the advice of the previous comments and use the data to create a rough initial guess for the parameters that can be used as the p0 parameter of curve_fit.

Comment: FWIW - managed to get this happening by inputting the formula for cauchy manually. In the end, a Moffat distribution is a perfect fit for the data though.
Cheers all!